# How do I avoid repeated range fetching with a Google spreadsheet script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a Google spreadsheet-based rostering system. At the moment I am working on validating that the roster meets legal requirements, and it's beginning to look like this could easily become very sluggish. Since I am only slightly above 'tinkerer' status when it comes to JS I seek the help of your good selves.

All of this is within a single spreadsheet. One sheet contains a list of shift definitions: each with a name, a start time and a finish time. Another sheet contains the actual roster, with dates in the rows and a column for each staff member, with each cell containing the name of the shift they will work that day.

One of the legal requirements is a minimum interval between shifts. I had been thinking that the script would, every time a staff member is allocated a new shift, check that against that person's previous shift to make sure that it is compliant.

At the moment for each comparison I'm running getDataRange() for both the sheet containing the list of shift definitions (to retrieve the start/finish times for the two shifts involved), and the sheet containing the roster itself (so that I can retrieve the previous day's shift). This occurs whenever the roster is edited, and range/value fetches are easily the most expensive call that my script has so far - often 200ms+.

I'd rather just preserve the first range I fetched for each sheet while the spreadsheet was open, but as I understand it GApps scripts do not lend themselves to this. I did have a look at the Properties service but it looks like if I were to use it for this I would have to dump everything into strings - would this be slower still?

I realise I could avoid this by just checking everything on-demand in one pass, but I would like to have an in-line validation if it is possible without slowing everything to a crawl, because mistakes in one part of the roster can have knock-on effects elsewhere so it is better to fix errors as they arise.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

edit - relevant code snippet below.

```
function validate(event)
{
    var sheet = event.source;
    var rng = event.range;
    var prev = sheet.getDataRange().offset(rng.getRowIndex()-2,rng.getColumnIndex()-1,1,1);
    return D22CheckString(rng.getValue(),prev.getValue());
}
```

This is called every time something is added to the roster, and I am calling getDataRange() every time to get the value of the cell immediately above the one that fired the event. I'd like not to do that because each fetch takes so long.

Comment: You should include the (gist of the) code of your `onEdit` triggered function.  

You probably won't be able to use PropertiesService due to quota limits, at least for an onEdit function.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: Some of that doesn't seem valid per se. [(`event.source` is a `Spreadsheet`, not a `Sheet`)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit). The goal of `prev` is to point to the value immediately above the modified cell?

Comment: Yes, that's what `prev` is for. It has been working for me so far, but the getDataRange() call there is particularly expensive. Is that retrieving the data ranges of the whole spreadsheet then, not just the active sheet?

Comment: calling it from the workbook is definitely more expensive than it needs to be for your usage, where you want a single cell with known and constant relationship to the just-edited cell.

Answer (score 0):

The `validate` function you've posted can be improved to avoid `getDataRange()` entirely:

```
function validate(event)
{
  var prev = event.range.offset(-1, 0).getValue();
  return D22CheckString(event.value, prev);
}
```

You can improve the performance of the other part of your `onEdit` function through the use of Google's [CacheService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cache). With a cache, you can build a lookup object in the first call (or any call made where there is no cached value available), and then store it for extremely quick access by the following calls (much faster than interacting with the Spreadsheet API to get values, at least).

My example uses a helper function `ProcessShifts()` to call `getDataRange()` for the sheet with shift data and construct an associative array between the named shift and its key properties (like the `startTime` and `endTime`). Before returning the new object, it caches the stringified result for a few minutes. You'd then update your D22CheckString function to use this `shifts` map, likely by passing it as an argument:

```
var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
function validate(event)
{
  var cached = cache.get(<key>);
  var shifts = {};
  if(cached)
    shifts = JSON.parse(cached);
  else
    shifts = ProcessShifts(event.source);

    var prev = event.range.offset(-1, 0).getValue();
  return D22CheckString(shifts, event.value, prev);
}


// This makes a shift map with start and end properties, e.g.:
// shifts["9 - 5"].start -> 9
// shifts["9 - 5"].end   -> 17
function ProcessShifts(source)
{
  // source is the event.source, i.e. the triggering workbook.
  var inputs = source.getSheetByName(<shift sheet name>).getDataRange().getValues();
  // Clear out any previous data in the shifts map.
  shifts = {};
  // inputs is a rectangular array with row and column indexing
  for(var row = 1; row < inputs.length; ++row)
  {
    // (These indices 0, 1, 2... likely have to be changed.)
    var shiftName = inputs[row][0];
    var shiftStart = inputs[row][1];
    var shiftEnd = inputs[row][2];
    shifts[shiftName] = {start: shiftStart, end: shiftEnd};
  }
  cache.put(<key>, JSON.stringify(shifts));
  return shifts;
}
```

You could add range / sheet logic in your `validate` function to remove the cached shifts object if you are editing the shifts page.
Error checking to cover things like an employee not scheduled on the previous day, or a typo in a shift name, etc. is recommended.

Comment: I get most of what you're saying, thank you. The only thing I don't understand is `cache` being declared outside any function rather than being passed between the two. I thought variables couldn't be persistent?

Comment: Variables can absolutely be "persistent," but only during a given execution. Whenever any apps-script function is called, all globals get evaluated as a part of the script startup / provisioning. For you, when the `onEdit` function is triggered, `cache` gets instantiated, then `onEdit` is called. When `onEdit` (and any functions it called) wrap up, `cache` is cleared as the script instance destroys itself. (This execution-limited scope is why "expensive" globals are bad, since they get created for every function invocation.)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear in my comment. I meant that variables can't persist between executions, as you say. 

I think I understand now that variables can be declared outside of functions but they are cleared when the execution ends. But how does use of `cache` help if it's cleared at the end of the execution like any variable would be? It seems that would only speed up repeated range fetches in a single execution, but there would only be a single fetch per execution. Sorry I'm being dense, I still don't get it.

Comment: `CacheService` does let you store data between executions. They have some requirements on size and duration, but that's to be expected. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service

Comment: @electricaltill [glad my answer was able to help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)